# Why windows 11 does not support old cpu?

Tags: operating-systems, cpu

I know CPUs execute machine language code. Also I know operating systems such as Windows and Linux are a piece of code. But I cannot understand why Windows 11 does not run on a somewhat old CPU.

Can anyone explain it please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about marketing and has nothing to do with computer science.

Answer (score 2):

It´s an artifical barrier set by Microsoft that requires a **TPM 2.0**, intended to enhance system security.

A TPM is a so-called **Trusted Platform Module**, a piece of security hardware on a chip (in this case the CPU) that can be trusted for several security relevant things like storing keys etc. It also has a unique own key as shipped that can be used to verify it as a platform.

Many not-so-old CPUs have a TPM on them, but don´t support the rather new TPM 2.0 version.

Microsoft claims to enhance Windows 11 security by requiring it:
*"Today, we are announcing Windows 11 to raise security baselines with new hardware security requirements built-in that will give our customers the confidence that they are even more protected from the chip to the cloud on certified devices."*

Yes, it is something controversial. My own desktop with its 5 year old CPU doesn´t support TPM 2.0. Microsoft alienated a lot of customers with that.

Comment: He asks about CPU, not TPM module. Your system can have TPM 2.0, but have old CPU. Windows 11 requires both TPM 2.0 and new CPU (some list of them).

Comment: TPM is mostly a motherboard thing but, by specifying the CPU, Microsoft achieves to also specify the motherboard. CPUs run on specified sockets and later gen CPUs will require a different socket (a new motherboard). I think it actually has a lot to do with TPM mostly related to profit making (they co-benefit from new hardware sales with other companies).

Comment: @user123 Thanks. Indeed, I myself really think so! I suppose that -1 is also related to your point! :))

Comment: This seems a good answer. However, the question will be closed on this site as it is off-topic. If you like your own answer, I would recommend you click the "Flag" button on the question, then "in need of moderator intervention", request that the question be migrated to "Super User" site.  That site is the general software/hardware site. It handles Windows, Mac, as well as Unix and Linux.